# Kivy. Проблема с предачей и отображением переменных между Screen в ScreenManager

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, kivy

Уже неделю бьюсь над одной проблемой, перепробовал море вариантов и не один не работает. Суть такова: приложение kivy с .kv, построено с использованием ScreenManager. Есть три класса Screen - First, Second и Result. Первый принимает данные через TextInput, вызывает второй, который принимает аналогичным образом еще набор данных, вызывает функцию обработки данных, затем вызывает третий для отображения результата, и вот здесь загвоздка - передать данные и отобразить результат с лету не удается.
Единственное решение которое удалось найти - добавление дополнительной кнопки в третий класс, которая вызывает функцию из этого же класса для отображения ранее расчитаного результата. Может кто подскажет как обойтись без этого лишнего шага?

example.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

def result():
    name = FirstScreen.entries + SecondScreen.entries
    res = 0
    for i in name:
        res += i
    bolwan = '''[size=20sp]Сумма данных: %s [/size]\n\n'''
    mes = bolwan % (res)
    return mes

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    entries = []

    def fetch_screen(self):
        hp = []
        for key in self.ids.keys():
            s = self.ids[key].text
            if s == '':
                print("Не введено значение")
                return
            try:
                d = float(s)
            except:
                print("Введено недопустимое значение")
                return
            else:
                hp.append(d)
        self.entries.extend(hp)
        MyExampleApp.sm.current = 'second'

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    entries = []

    def fetch_screen(self):
        hp = []
        for key in self.ids.keys():
            s = self.ids[key].text
            if s == '':
                print("Не введено значение")
                return
            try:
                d = float(s)
            except:
                print("Введено недопустимое значение")
                return
            else:
                hp.append(d)
        self.entries.extend(hp)
        mes = result()
        ResultScreen().mes_f(mes)
        MyExampleApp.sm.current = 'result'

class ResultScreen(Screen):

    def mes_f(self, mes):
        self.ids.res_lab.text = mes


class MyExampleApp(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()

    def quit(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        Window.close()

    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='first'))
        self.sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
        self.sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyExampleApp().run()
```

myexample.kv

```
<MyContainer@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 1, 0.1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos:self.pos

<MyLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    font_size: '18sp'

<FirstScreen>:
    MyContainer:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 10, 0, 0, 0
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MyLabel:
                    text: 'Данные №1'
                MyLabel:
                    text: 'Данные №2'
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 0, 0, 10, 0
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    id: dn_1
                TextInput:
                    id: dn_2
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            on_press: root.fetch_screen()

<SecondScreen>:
    MyContainer:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 10, 0, 0, 0
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MyLabel:
                    text: 'Данные №3'
                MyLabel:
                    text: 'Данные №4'
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 0, 0, 10, 0
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    id: dn_3
                TextInput:
                    id: dn_4
        Button:
            text: 'Расчитать'
            on_press: root.fetch_screen()

<ResultScreen>:
    MyContainer:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Результаты'
            font_size: '25sp'
        Label:
            id: res_lab
            markup: True
            text: ''
        Button:
            text: 'Выход'
            on_press: app.quit(
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом:
example.py:

```
...

def result():
    ...
    mes = bolwan % (res)
    # ссылка на SreenManager
    sm = App.get_running_app().root
    # ссылка на необходимый Screen
    resultscreen = sm.get_screen('result')
    # изменяем нужную метку
    resultscreen.ids.res_lab.text = mes

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    ...

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    entries = []

    def fetch_screen(self):
        ...
        self.entries.extend(hp)
        result()
        MyExampleApp.sm.current = 'result'

class ResultScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyExampleApp(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()

    def quit(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        Window.close()

    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='first'))
        self.sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
        self.sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyExampleApp().run()
```